# Create instance of ISet(of String)

Tags: vb.net, list, instance

I am struggling. Got properties that are of type ISet(of String) and I need to assign them with value.

```
.Add()
```

throws empty link error since it is not instantiated, been trying to create an instance, assign value and pass with set(), but

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(MyClass.MyProperty)
```

throws empty link. Neither this solution [Visual Basic: dynamically create objects using a string as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432317/visual-basic-dynamically-create-objects-using-a-string-as-the-name) works, I ve output the list and ISet is simply not there.
I've been trying to solve this for a while now.

Comment: The class which implements the property ought to be initializing the underlying object, not the consuming code.  `ISet` is an interface, so you can use it to declare objects and cast to it, but you cannot create instances of them; they are simply a contract of what methods and properties a given type (class) will implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces don't fully define objects. They only define one part of an object, and therefore you don't have enough information from the `ISet(Of String)` interface on it's own to create an instance.

What you need to do is find a type that implements the interface, and create one of those... `HashSet(Of String)` and `SortedSet(Of String)` would both work.