# Dynamically Add UserControl to Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to dynamically add a usercontrol to a form in VB.Net. I will be pulling the UserControl name (String) from a database and if that UserControl exists in the project I would like it to be added to the form. 
I know how to programmatically add usercontrols to a form, but I am not sure how when using a string for the name.

```
Dim userContName As UserControl = dtModules.Rows(k).Item("uc_Name")
Panel1.Controls.Add(userContName)
```

I attempted this soultion

```
Public Sub LoadGroups()
dtModules = Tbl_GroupModulesTableAdapter1.GetDataBy_spGetModuleByGroup(grp.Name)
For k = 0 To dtModules.Rows.Count - 1
   If grp.Name = dtModules.Rows(k).Item("Module_Group") Then 
        Dim fullyQualifiedClassName As String = dtModules.Rows(k).Item("Module_Name")
        If fullyQualifiedClassName = Nothing Then
        Else
            Dim o = fetchInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName)
            Dim b = CType(o, Control)
            grp.Controls.Add(b)
        End If
   End If
Next
End Sub

Public Function fetchInstance(ByVal fullyQualifiedClassName As String) As Object
    Dim nspc As String = fullyQualifiedClassName.Substring(0, fullyQualifiedClassName.LastIndexOf("."c))
    Dim o As Object = Nothing
    Try
        For Each ay In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()
            If (ay.Name = nspc) Then
                o = Assembly.Load(ay).CreateInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
    Return o
End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic: dynamically create objects using a string as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432317/visual-basic-dynamically-create-objects-using-a-string-as-the-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it to work with this;

```
Dim ucName As String = Projectname.UserControlName
Dim newType As Type = Type.[GetType](ucName, True, True)
Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(newType)
Form.Controls.Add(o)
```

Once I got this it was pretty simple! thanks for the feedback!