# Use contents stored in string as a new variable name

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use the value of a string variable to become the name of my new variable.  For example see, below code.  Reason I'm doing this is I have a text file containing the names of the variables I need to create objects for.  Perhaps there is another way to do this?

```
  Dim mystring As String
  mystring = "Variablename"
  'dim "Variablename" as object
```

Comment: Nope. Well, not without emitting code, which is crazy difficult.  So, what we have here is an X/Y problem.  You should [edit] and give a full explanation of *what you are trying to do* or *what problem you are trying to solve* with this.

Comment: You'll probably need to use reflection.  [this one may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432317/visual-basic-dynamically-create-objects-using-a-string-as-the-name)

Comment: Sounds like a dictionary could work, it provides the same "service" as a variable would...it would give you the ability to call values from memory by name, which is what a variable is at its root

Comment: Once you've got the variable, what are you going to do with it?  The code which uses the variable needs to know the variable name too...

Comment: I recommend using a dictionary as described below.  Other options to investigate include the ExpandoObject class; CodeDom, which builds an assembly dynamically; or using System.Linq.Expression, but I suspect these aren't really the right choice for whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a collection?  The *key* of the items in the collection would be your variable name, and the *value* of the items in the collection are your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a class with custom properties. If you do want to go this route, this should help you:

```
' Note: There is no root namespace in the project properties
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports System.Reflection

Namespace Foo

    Module Module1

        Sub Main()
            Dim instance = createInstance({"Prap", "Prep", "Prip", "Prop", "Prup"})
            instance.Prap = "Prappy"
            Console.WriteLine(instance.Prap)
        End Sub

        Private Function createInstance(propertyNames As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Object
            Dim codeProvider As New VBCodeProvider()
            Dim codeCompiler As ICodeCompiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler()
            Dim compilerParameters As New CompilerParameters()
            compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:library"
            Dim code =
                "NameSpace Foo" & Environment.NewLine &
                "    Partial Public Class Bar" & Environment.NewLine
            For Each name In propertyNames
                code &=
                String.Format("        Public Property {0} As String", name) & Environment.NewLine
            Next
            code &= "    End Class" & Environment.NewLine &
                "End Namespace"
            Console.WriteLine("Code to compile:")
            Console.WriteLine(code)
            Dim result = codeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, code)
            If result.Errors.HasErrors Then
                Console.WriteLine(result.Errors.OfType(Of CompilerError).Aggregate(Of String)("Errors:", Function(e1, e2) e1 & ", " & e2.ErrorText))
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Success")
                Dim type As Type = result.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Foo.Bar")
                Dim instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
                Return instance
            End If

        End Function

    End Module

End Namespace
```

Output:

> Code to compile:
>   
> NameSpace Foo
>   
>     Partial Public Class Bar
>   
>         Public Property Prap As String
>   
>         Public Property Prep As String
>   
>         Public Property Prip As String
>   
>         Public Property Prop As String
>   
>         Public Property Prup As String
>   
>     End Class
>   
> End Namespace
>   
> Success
>   
> Prappy

Now, you could also build the class with different property types than String, which is hard-coded. Just include it in the arguments either as a separate array, or you could use a Tuple or Dictionary etc. Good luck!