# VB.Net Create an instance of a class from name

Tags: vb.net, class, data-driven

I'm trying to data-drive part of my software so that I have a database table containing class names and some other properties. e.g.

```
"Bob.Foo"
"Bob.Baz"
"Bob.Flip"
```

Within my software, I want to create an instance of that class. There are several dozen classes and so I do not want is a form like this:

```
select case cClassName
    case "Bob.Foo": a = new Bob.Foo()
    case "Bob.Baz": a = new Bob.Baz()
    case "Bob.Flip": a = new Bob.Flip()
end select
```

Rather I'm looking for some function like this:

```
a = CreateAnInstanceOfThisClass(cClassName)
```

The classes all conform to an Interface class (IMyClass). If you're old and wisened enough , I'm looking for something like the old VB6 CreateObject function (remember that?).

Many thanks.

Comment: Look into Reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Basic: dynamically create objects using a string as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432317/visual-basic-dynamically-create-objects-using-a-string-as-the-name)

Comment: @MatSnow - you are right. Thank you. It's not always easy to find the right articles whiel searching.